# Hazard and precautionary statements

Tags: everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis

Is there a scientific database where one can find all the H and P statements for all chemicals? I would like to avoid using wikipedia but I can't find a database from a trusted source.

Comment: What do you mean by "*all chemicals*"? And what's wrong with the references usually posted at the end of every Wikipedia entry that are usually showing the origin of GHS statements?

Comment: @andselisk I meant the majority of chemicals. and the wikipedia entries aren't cited so the origin is unknown. I have just checked this with 2 examples.

Comment: There are some online sources such as Msdsonline.com, but I wouldn’t count on any of them being comprehensive. For common chemicals, though, just searching “msds [chemical name]” will often turn up something

Answer (score -1):

The most comprehensive one (so not "all" chemicals) that I've seen is the Aldrich website. By law they have to supply MSDS for everything they sell. However, they may ask for a lot number or the function may not work unless you're logged in as a customer.